# Executing another EXE from an application

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a windows application in C#. I have a form. There is a button and a panel(panel1) on that form. Now all I want is when I click on that button, it will fire another EXE (developed in .Net). I am successfull in doing so. But now the challenge lies in opening that EXE in the panel (panel1) present in the form.

Any help !!

Comment: Opening an EXE in a Panel component ? What kind of EXE you are trying to execute ?

Comment: do you want to "embed" an external app in your own app ?

Comment: The 2nd Exe , which I am trying to open is developed in VB.Net. If there is no way I can control the position / anchoring of the 2nd application so that it opens up in the panel control of the 1st form, then what is the next best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using traditional C# and managed environment, I don't think that its possible. You can try a) using interop/p-invoke to deal with WinAPIs to do what you want b) if you have created both these C# apps then you can move the second app to be an MDI child i.e. a separate form and all (if its a windows app, otherwise, just live with it :)).